# Ajax call does not work for this simple code

Tags: ajax

I have this ajax call which gets the value from a hidden input field

```
<p>
    <input type="hidden" name="GreetingAll" id="GreetingAll" value="Hello Everyone!" />  
    <input type="submit" id="PleasePushMe" />  
    <div id="test-div1">  
    </div>
</p>  

jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    var GreetingAll = jQuery("#GreetingAll").val(); 
    alert(GreetingAll); 
    jQuery("#PleasePushMe").click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'http://www.yoursitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  
            data: {  
                action: 'MyAjaxFunction',  
                GreetingAll: GreetingAll,  
            },  
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){  
                jQuery("#test-div1").html('');  
                jQuery("#test-div1").append(data);  
            },  
            error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
                alert(errorThrown);  
            }  
            });  
      });  
  });
```

the functions fails to return or do anything

inspite of including these functions , in the function.php

```
function add_myjavascript(){  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-implementation.js', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/scripts/ajax-implementation.js", array( 'jquery' ) );  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'add_myjavascript' );
function MyAjaxFunction(){  
    //get the data from ajax() call  
    $GreetingAll = $_POST['GreetingAll '];  
    $results = "<h2>".$GreetingAll."</h2>";  
    // Return the String  
    die($results);  
}  
// creating Ajax call for WordPress  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );
```

Any idea why is this code not working?

Comment: Could you the next time you post a question please take the time to format your code readable? Thank you! Btw: There're spaces in function calls, etc. Turn on `WP_DEBUG` and PHP error reporting and show us your error output.

Answer (score 3):

You have a space in your function name on the action call,

```
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );  
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_ MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );
```

...should be,

```
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );  
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );
```

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the question. All the best.